# How do you calculate how much a number is above or below a given number to another number.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working to figure out how to calculate the difference (or the distance, unsure of terminology) between a center (Given maybe?) number and another number. I want to know what that number would be. Here is an example.

If i have a set of numbers for instance, 2 is our center(given) number.

1 **2** 3 4

How would i calculate that 1 is one number behind 2 (-1) or 4 is two numbers ahead of 2 (+2). Is there a mathematical way of representing that distance?

Comment: Substract the 'center' from the number...

Comment: Welp, that was easy, my brain wanted it to be harder than it was.